# SQL Query to search by name(containing combination of two or more word)

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

When i search by using

```
....LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%'.....
```

Then it returns all the rows containing `txtName`. It is okay for name like

- Bijay or
- Bijay kumar.

  And rows contains data like
- Bijay,
- Bijay kumar kush,
- Bijay kush.

In this case it should return, `Bijay kumar kush` and `Bijay Kush` when search by using `txtName` like `Bijay Kush`. But not getting the output like this. It is empty when search by using first name and last name without supplying middle name.Here`txtName`is the Full Name text Box used for searching the name.I want to know where am I making the mistake.Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.I am using this type of query which doesn't return the result if searched without middle name as stated above.

```
...
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text))
       SearchSqlDataSource.SelectCommand += " AND (New_Employees.Full_Name LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%' OR New_Employees.Full_Name LIKE '%" + txtName.Text + "%')
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build your sql query. Instead use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection and other issues.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware about the SQl injection @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might suggest replacing all spaces with the wildcard character.  You can do this in the application or the database. Assuming the underlying database is SQL Server, here is the database code:

```
WHERE New_Employees.Full_Name LIKE REPLACE('%" + txtName.Text + "%', ' ', '%')
```

Comment: Brilliant!
Also, if you split `txtName.Text` on white space, and recombine different arrangements of the text interspersed with wildcards, it could make for a much more sophisticated name search query, albeit a little slower.